# Unknown properties using inheritance

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In Angular and TypeScript I have an interface

```
export interface A {
  name: string;
}
```

Now two other interfaces, which inherit from it:

```
 export interface B extends A {
  year: number;
}


 export interface C extends A {
  place: string;
}
```

Now how do I go about it, when using it as an Input in an Angular Component:

```
@Input()
obj: A;
```

So with this I say, I don't care if I get object B or C, it needs to be of type A. But this will lead to errors once I call

```
obj.year;
```

because of course year doesn't exist on objects of type A only on type B.

I see I can do:

```
@Input
obj: B|C;
```

But it seems wrong and also doesn't work. Isn't there a more generic way to use inheritance?

Comment: "*So with this I say, I don't care if I get object B or C, it needs to be of type A*" then why do you call `obj.year` if that will only be available on B? It suggests that you are expecting a B type.

Comment: If you do want to conditionally do stuff on `B` type objects in a function that takes `A|B`, check out typeguards.

Comment: @VLAZ Well I have a check before, so it only gets executed, when it's B.  I kind of don't get around seperating them in two different components.

Answer (score 0):

Union types is the best way to do this, if you expect `obj` to be just of types `B` or `C`. Using `A` means the object could be of type `A` or **any** sub-type (of which there are an infinity, not just `B` or `C`)

Inheritance here helps you inherit all properties of `A` into `B` and `C`, that is where it's usefulness ends.

Using `B | C` also enables you to use type guards to access properties which are not common to both `B` and `C` (you can't access specific fields by default, unless you perform some sort of check to see what is actually in `obj` at run-time):

```
if('year' in this.obj) {
    this.obj.year //ok
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQICCCA3sAhRStgLYgBcCAznDKgOYDcwAvqJLESp0WPAQBCCcOhQATJkVLlKCAJ4hsMRigCuNAEYZufYP2jxkaDDnwIAwlLAz5isioQQANmMYs2KLl5TXG8mBTsoGggldyh9ACsAQkZJAB97bncaAAoAShj3FSRMBGyAcnVNMssEOAALJCYAOjj4-LdCztqG5tamypgEAHohqABrZS6eKU8mAg6u93rGloSmrzFh0YnFhD53Ph4gA)

Comment: @user5417542 I added a full playground example, let me know what does not work for you

Comment: You may have to use `this.obj['year']` to avoid the compilation error.

Comment: @ConnorsFan not under `noImplictAny`, and I don't really recommend this. You are just getting around the type system, not using it, for something that is a common use case with a common TS pattern

Answer (score 0):

if You want the Input to either use B or C you could also add a generic argument to the class. You can use the parent A to add restriction on the class

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your input the same type as it is now but when you are using it you could use type casting. you can do something like this:

```
(obj as B).year
```

It won't complain anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an interface D with both of the properties, only set them to optional.

```
export interface A {
  name: string;
}

export interface D extends A {
  year?: number;
  place?: string;
}
```

After this you can call `year` of `place` optional.